# How to generate an incremental item number in BOPF

Tags: abap

I created a custom table to store reasons for modifying an Object. I'm doing a POC with BOPF in order to learn, even it may not make sense to use it here.

This is how the persistent structure looks like (simplified):

```
define type zobject_modifications {
  object_id       : zobject_id;
  @EndUserText.label : 'Modification Number'
  mod_num         : abap.numc(4);
  reason_id       : zreason_id;
  @EndUserText.label : 'Modification Comments'
  comments        : abap.string(256);
}
```

The alternative key consists in the **object_id + mod_num**. The **mod_num** should be an auto-generated counter, always adding 1 to the last modification for the object_id.

I created a determination **before_save** to generate it, checking the MAX **mod_num** from the database BOs and from the current instantiated BOs and increasing by 1.

But when I try to create 2 BOs for the same object in a single transaction, I get an error because of the duplicated alternative key, since the field **MOD_NUM** is still initial and the **before_save** would be triggered later. I tried to change the determination to "After Modify" but I still get the same problem.

The question is: When and how should I generate the next MOD_NUM to be able to create multiple nodes for the same object ID safely?

This must be a very common problem so there must be a best practice way to do it, but I was not able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [number range](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5db4c2a406234b6995553939c79da063/7.52.5/en-US/48d58f50982b424be10000000a421937.html) to produce sequential identifiers. They ensure that you won't get duplicates if there are ongoing and concurrent transactions.

If you want to insist on determining the next identifier on your own, use the `io_read` input parameter of the determination to retrieve the biggest `mod_num`:

The database contains only those nodes that have already been committed. But your new nodes are not committed, yet, such that you won't get them.

`io_read` in contrast accesses BOPF's temporary buffer that also contains the nodes you just created, hence seeing the more actual data.

Comment: How do I use number range for a subobject which parent object ID is not a range itself? Regarding using ``io_read``, I use it for to check the nodes in the buffer as you said but it does not return the ones in the DB, so to prevent using a full query, I just do a ``SELECT MAX()`` in the database too and then determine what is the latest. Is there a way that ``io_read`` may return all the nodes for a given ``object_id``?

Comment: `io_read` doesn't offer so much query flexibility as to emulate a `SELECT MAX()`. But you should be able to retrieve_by_association all modifications that affect the object at hand. You're probably right about the number range not fitting here; I didn't realize that `mod_num` would start again at 1 for each object.

Comment: OK thank you. Then I think I will leave the logic the way I have it, but I still need to generate the ``mod_num`` before the ***duplicate alternative key*** error is triggered and I'm not sure where to do that